# keycloak: google login character encoding error

Tags: java, character-encoding, single-sign-on, keycloak, google-signin

We are using **keycloak standalone** server to authenticate our users.
Social IDPs: google and facebook login work perfectly, except the following mistake:

> If on your google account first and last names are written with **non-ascii
>   characters**, keycloak doesn't read them properly.

For instance: Name on the google account is *Собиров Валижон*.
What I get on keycloak is **РЎРѕР±РёСЂРѕРІ Р’Р°Р»РёР¶РѕРЅ**

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- add test realm and client
- add google identity provider settings
- login with google user who has non-ascii chars in first or lastname (in my
  case Собиров Валижон)
- see keycloak test realms user database

It would be appreciated if someone could solve the issue.

[screenshot from keycloak account](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12BFeK66S646FeVS9hmf1LHvkkaSk7A9q/view)

[screenshot from google account](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-B57ohP7jTa7xRv5ZvH9EoKXcooDJJeh/view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to put default encoding in JVM.

Add default encoding to **standalone.conf**

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OTPS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue when localising my custom keycloak provider.

Putting `# encoding: utf-8` on top of every `messages_XX.properties` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try read this internationalization issues in official documentation. I also had troubles with non-ascii chars and it helped ;)
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#internationalization

And maybe you should see your keycloack settings in keycloack client like here. I assume that your language need to be allowed here.
[image]